# change form controls validation, dynamically and apply new validation immediately in angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have several forms and I need custom validation on #form2 inputs based on #form1 user selection. I wrote a custom validation (it's not complete yet).

Custom Validator:

```
@Injectable()
export class Checks {

    constructor(public prescConfigService: PrescConfigService) { }

    validity(section, key: string): ValidatorFn | null {
        const condition = this.prescConfigService.getDefaultSetting(section, key);
        if (!condition) {
            console.log('if there is no condition (not selected): ', condition);
            return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
                console.log('control1: ', control);
                return null;
            };
        } else {
            console.log('elseeeee', condition);
            return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
                console.log('control2: ', control);
                return { 'required': true };
            };
        }
    }
}
```

form2 creation:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
      NationalNum: [this.prescConfigService.getValueByField('CustomerNationalNum'), {
        validator: [this.checks.validity('insurance', 'CheckNationalNum')],
        updateOn: 'change'
      }],
      BirthDateJalali: [this.prescConfigService.getValueByField('BirthDate'), Validators.required],
      Cellphone: [this.prescConfigService.getValueByField('Cellphone'), Validators.required],
      Sex: [this.prescConfigService.getValueByField('SexID'), Validators.required],
    });
```

All I need is that the custom validation applies when user changes the select from #form1 (which is on different component). Is there anyway?

Comment: Create a subject that will keep track of the changes happening in component1 for that specific dropdown, then in component 2, subscribe to that subject, and have a variable inside that subscription. In your validator then, just do your condition based on that variable.

Comment: I did this and worked for me. thank you @callback